# Inline XML Element Attribute creation in msxml2 VBA

Tags: vba, attributes, msxml

I'm working on some VBA to take some excel data and produce some XML which is then passed over to a SQL procedure for further processing.

Unfortunately, I'm having an issue attaching an xml attribute to an element.

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Tester()

Dim objDom As Object
Set objDom = CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set objRootElem = objDom.CreateElement("Allocations")
objDom.AppendChild objRootElem

objRootElem.AppendChild(objDom.CreateElement("Employee55")).Text = "Test Element Value"

MsgBox (objDom.XML)

End Sub
```

This produces XML that looks like this:

```
<Allocations><Employee55>Test Element Value</Employee55></Allocations>
```

However what I'm after is additional attributes against the Employee55 element like this:

```
<Allocations><Employee55 EmpID="10" EmpDob="01021986">Test Element Value</Employee55></Allocations>
```

I know if i declare the Employee object an object, and two additional Attribute objects, I can use Element.SetAttributeNode and pass in the Attribute object.

But in this scenario, its dynamic and I don't have the Element in memory to work this way.

I'm looking for a way to do this inline, much like I've added the .Text value to the Employee55 element.

Any advice?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think you can do that inline - too many operations involved in creating and attaching the attribute

Answer (score 2):

This isn't "inline" I suppose, but hardly a hardship:

```
Private Sub Tester2()
    Dim Dom As Object

    Set Dom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With Dom
        With .appendChild(.createElement("Allocations"))
            With .appendChild(Dom.createElement("Employee55"))
                .Text = "Test Element Value"
                .setAttribute "EmpID", "10"
                .setAttribute "EmpDob", "01021986"
            End With
        End With
        MsgBox .xml
    End With
End Sub
```